# What were Nick Fury and Maria Hill up to during Civil War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, marvel, behind-the-scenes, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*, there's no sign of either Nick Fury or Maria Hill, both of whom were prominent allies to the Avengers even after the events of *Captain America: Winter Soldier*. We know from *Avengers: Age of Ultron* that Hill was working for Stark, but still we don't see her in the film. **Is there any  info on where they were, what they were doing, etc.?** In-universe is preferred but out-of-universe is okay too.

---

<sub>I'm only halfway through season 3 of Agents of SHIELD so please hide any spoilers that may be related to that show. Thanks.</sub>

Comment: After *Age of Ultron*, I'm not sure that everyone is generally aware that Nick Fury is alive; Maria Hill works for Tony Stark but not really the Avengers.

Comment: I guess the real reason could be that the film already had many characters to juggle. Also I'm not too sure if Hill still works for Stark. She was shown for a few seconds in the new avengers facility at the end of Age of Ultron. Nick Fury also seemed to be back in "director mode" black jacket and all, so both characters really just vanished and had no mention in Civil War. However, I do believe that since they were prominent in some films, their absence should be explained in one of the up coming films.

Answer (score 9):

### Nicky Fury: Not even the writers know.

[The LA Times](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/herocomplex/la-et-hc-nick-fury-civil-war-20160509-snap-story.html) asked the screenwriters for *Civil War* this question directly.

> I'm curious. Where was Fury?
>
> Stephen McFeely: I'm curious too!
>
> Christopher Markus: We called him, but he let the line blink. Primarily it felt like one too many possible opinions. We didn't want him to take one side or the other, because that's not his place in the universe. And then we didn't want another, "Is he still with the government? Is he opposed to the government but supporting the government?” It got to be the potential for a lot more polemic discussion that the movie did not have room for.

Samuel Jackson spoke with [Collider](http://collider.com/samuel-l-jackson-wants-to-extend-marvel-contract-is-not-in-civil-war/) and said

> But I’m not in Captain America 3. I can’t figure that out, but I’m not. I guess I’m still out there, trying to figure out what happened to S.H.I.E.L.D. and who these other people are.

---

### Maria Hill: if anyone knows, they're not saying

[The Daily Beast](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/07/24/cobie-smulders-on-life-after-how-i-met-your-mother.html) asked Cobie Smulders if she was even going to show up in *Civil War* or *Infinity War*, and she dodged the question entirely.

> *Will we see you pop up in Captain America: Civil War or the Avengers’ Infinity Wars films?*
>
> That’s really sweet that you asked me, but I can’t talk about that. I’ll get in trouble!